# .NET app taking long time to show pages

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have a .NET web app that is taking a long time to load each page.  I think there is network activity that is going on or calls to other sites.  How can I track what network / internet activity is going on when the page is loading?  Is there some utility that would allow me to trace activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try [Fiddler2](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/). It is a local proxy that tracks all the http activity in and out of your box. If you need to check other protocols, you should look into [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/). Wireshark allows you to analyze all traffic in and out of your box.

Answer (score 1):

I had a problem along those lines a few years ago.  I installed WinPcap on the server and had it log all of the network activity.  Turns out an errant 3rd party control was sending ~1MB of garbage data back to the server every time a client callback of any sort occurred.  I removed it and the page load/callback performance shot up about 500%.